# whereNear query doesn't seem to work properly in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm working on an Android app related to Geolocations. I'm using Parse as backend. 
I need to display results based on user's current location.

I'm using this query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Restaurants"); 
ParseGeoPoint sLatlong = new ParseGeoPoint(currentLat, currentLong);
        query.whereNear("rest_location", sLatlong);
```

But the results are not sorted distance wise.

Can someone help me out.

Comment: You know Parse is shutting down right? In January 2017 their service will be shut down. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Yeah I know that. I'll be using this just for 3 months, to validate my idea.

Comment: As a side note to my answer when you say the results are not sorted distance wise are you checking the order of the results in the `FindCallback.done(...)` method? Otherwise where else are you checking for the order of the results? Maybe you are changing the order yourself after processing the results.

Comment: What's the problem in sorting results by yourself?:)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Android Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints-geo-queries) for Parse the default sort order should already be by distance (nearest to farthest) unless you are specifying another sort order yourself.

Also, you might want to look into the `ParseQuery.whereWithin*` methods as you can specify you only want locations within a certain number of miles, kilometers, etc.

If all else fails and the sort order just doesn't want to work on the returned locations you can always sort them yourself by looping through the `ParseObject`s  returned from the query and using `ParseObject.getParseGeoPoint("rest_location")`.

That will return a `ParseGeoPoint` object and you can then do the following

```
ParseGeoPoint.distanceInKilometersTo(sLatlong);
```

To get the distance to the user's location and sort on that.

For reference here is a sample `Comparator`:

```
public class UserLocationComparator  implements Comparator<ParseObject> {

    private final ParseGeoPoint userLoc;

    public UserLocationComparator(ParseGeoPoint userLoc) {
        this.userLoc = userLoc;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ParseObject po1, ParseObject po2) {
        ParseGeoPoint loc1 = po1.getParseGeoPoint("rest_location");
        ParseGeoPoint loc2 = po2.getParseGeoPoint("rest_location");

        return loc1 == null ?
                (loc2 == null ? 0 : 1) :
                (loc2 == null ? -1 : Double.compare(userLoc.distanceInKilometersTo(loc1), userLoc.distanceInKilometersTo(loc2)));
    }
}
```

and then assuming you have a `List<ParseObject> results;` simply do:

```
Collections.sort(results, new UserLocationComparator(sLatlong));
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step1:** 
First of all you need to check whether your column "rest_location" is of type "GeoPoint". 
If it is then you should get results sorted by distance automatically with the code written by you. Only problem can be that "rest_location" is not of geopoint type or else there is some problem with Parse.
As per parse documentation : 
https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints
It gives by default results in sorted order (nearest to farthest) from userLocation.

If it doesn't work then you should use your own comparator.

```
 class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<ParseObject> {

    ParseGeoPoint userGeoPoint;

    public DistanceComparator(ParseGeoPoint geoPoint) {
      userGeoPoint = geoPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ParseObject lhs, ParseObject rhs) {
      double dist1 = lhs.getParseGeoPoint("rest_location").distanceInKilometersTo(userGeoPoint);
      double dist2 = rhs.getParseGeoPoint("rest_location").distanceInKilometersTo(userGeoPoint);

      return Double.compare(dist1,dist2);
    }
  }
```

Now you can simply pass 
Collections.sort(locationList, new DistanceComparator(sLatLong));